# GCC cannot compile: '* does not name a type'

Tags: c++, gcc

Today, after Slackware 13.37 installation, i've got the problem: default GCC 4.5.2 cannot compile my code. Now I study C++ by the Stephen Davis's book "C++ for dummies" and want to compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{

int nNCelsius;
cout << "Celsisus: ";
cin >> nNCelsius;

int nNFactor;
nNFactor = 212 - 32;

int nFahrenheit;
nFahrenheit = nNFactor * nNCelsius / 100 + 32;

cout << "Fahrenheit: ";
cout << nFahrenheit;

return 0;
}
```

But my GCC 4.5.2 gives these errors:

```
FahTCel.cpp:7:14: error: expected ')' before ';' token
FahTCel.cpp:7:14: error: 'main' declared as function returning a function
FahTCel.cpp:8:1: error: 'cout' does not name a type
FahTCel.cpp:9:1: error: 'cin' does not name a type
FahTCel.cpp:12:1: error: 'nNFactor' does not name a type
FahTCel.cpp:15:1: error: 'nFahrenheit' does not name a type
FahTCel.cpp:17:1: error: 'cout' does not name a type
FahTCel.cpp:18:1: error: 'cout' does not name a type
FahTCel.cpp:20:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'
FahTCel.cpp:21:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
```

Comment: Don't skip the first error message... you misspelled `#include <ionstream.h>` (rather badly, actually).  Next, [get a book that's up to date with at least the first version of the C++ standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I've never seen `<ionstream.h>`. All you should need to include is `<iostream>`. That book doesn't look like it has the best coding style.

Comment: Check this is correct **#include <ionstream.h>**, if not change.

Comment: I am curious when this book was published and which edition it is.  It must be a bit old (well, old in computer years...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three errors:

1. The correct header is `<iostream>`.  This program requires no other headers.
2. You must either put `using namespace std;` in the file, or refer to `std::cout` and `std::cin` explicitly.  Take your pick, plenty of C++ programmers disagree about which of the two options is better.  (You could also bring just `cin` and `cout` into your namespace, if you wanted.)
3. The program does not write a line terminator at the end.  This will cause the output to "look bad" on most terminals, with the command prompt appearing on the same line as the output.  For example:

Here are the corrections:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    cout << nFahrenheit << '\n';
    ...
}
```

**Note:** It is extremely unusual to see `main` take parameters with names other than `argc` and `argv`.  Changing the names just makes it harder for other people to read your code.

Answer (score 1):

its std::cout or you should add `using namespace std;`

and the include should be `< iostream>` not `< ionstream.h>`.